# Have chordal outerplanar graphs been studied before?

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory

Recall a graph is *chordal* if it contains no induced cycle of length 4 or more, and *outerplanar* if it has a crossing-free embedding in the plane such that all vertices are on the same face. While studying a certain problem, I came across *chordal outerplanar graphs*, which are graphs that are both chordal and outerplanar. [ISGCI](http://www.graphclasses.org/) didn't know of such a class. In fact, the closest thing I was able to find was the class of [chordal $\cap$ planar](http://www.graphclasses.org/classes/gc_985.html) graphs.

> Have chordal outerplanar graphs been studied before somewhere? What kind of properties do they have? Are they perhaps equivalent to some well-known (or a better known) graph class?

For example, it seems to me that every inner face of such a graph is a triangle. The motivation for the third question is that I got at most 5 hits when googling for such graphs, so I wonder if such graphs might be commonly known as something other than chordal outerplanar graphs.

Comment: You didn't try searching Google scholar for "chordal outerplanar", did you? It returns a small but nonzero number of hits. So the answer to "have they been studied before?" is yes.

Comment: @DavidEppstein I sure did (and my apologies for not mentioning this explicitly in the question. I know its part of the SE policies). For "outerplanar chordal" I got zero hits, and for "chordal outerplanar" I got 5 hits. I was expecting way more so it made me wonder if I'm even searching for the right thing (i.e. perhaps chordal outerplanar graphs are really known as X graphs, hence the question).

Comment: Probably the reason you didn't find more is that most research on graphs like this concerns maximal outerplanar graphs (almost the same thing, but with the additional requirement of being 2-connected). I get many more hits for them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, every inner face must be a triangle, as chords drawn outside a cycle prevent a drawing from being outerplanar.  Drawings of chordal graphs are then just triangulations of polygons; conversely, every triangulated polygon is outerplanar (certainly) and chordal (by induction, as cycles are sub-[triangulated polygons]).

Comment: If we take a union of two polygon triangulations that overlap at one vertex, wouldn't that be a graph that is outerplanar, chordal and and not a polygon triangulation? For me, the classification seems to be "a 2-disconnected union of polygon triangulations (and single edges and disconnected vertices)".

Comment: @JanDvorak wikified, feel free to edit that in (or post your own answer).